# Given $A^2+B^2=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}1402&2022\\2022&1402\end{smallmatrix}\right)$ for which $A,B\in M_2(\mathbb{R})$, show that $AB\neq BA$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

$M_2(\mathbb{R})$ is the set of all $2\times2$ matrices that their entries are in $\mathbb{R}$. Now consider $A,B\in M_2(\mathbb{R})$. We have
$$A^2+B^2=
\begin{bmatrix}1402&&2022\\
2022 && 1402\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Show that $AB\neq BA$.

I tried writing $(A+B)^2=A^2+AB+BA+B^2$ and we know if we assume $AB=BA$, then $(A+B)^2=A^2+2AB+B^2$. Then I tried to find the form of a squared matrix and compare these to reach a contradiction but I couldn't. I even don't know if it helps or not. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Hints.*

1. $A^2+B^2$ is a real symmetric $2\times2$ matrix with a positive trace and a negative determinant. Therefore, by a similarity transform, it can be diagonalised to some matrix $D=\operatorname{diag}(p,-q)$ with $p,q>0$. Now, let $A$ and $B$ be transformed to $X$ and $Y$ accordingly, so that $X^2+Y^2=D^2$. If $AB=BA$, then $XY=YX$. Hence both $X$ and $Y$ commutes with $D$. However, given that $D=\operatorname{diag}(p,-q)$, can you determine the set of all matrices that it commutes with?
2. Alternatively, note that $\det(A^2+B^2)=\det(A+iB)\det(A-iB)=|\det(A+iB)|^2$ when $AB=BA$.

Answer (score 1):

Slightly different solution, in my opinion more elementary.
Suppose that $AB=BA$. Then both of matrices commute with the matrix in the right-hand side.
It follows that matrices $A$ and $B$ have the form:
$$
A=
\left(
  \begin{array}{cc}
    x & y \\
    y & x \\
  \end{array}
\right),\
B=
\left(
  \begin{array}{cc}
    u & v \\
    v & u \\
  \end{array}
\right).
$$
Then
$$
x^2+y^2+u^2+v^2=1402
$$
and
$$
2xy+2uv=2022.
$$
Subtracting the second equality from the first, we get
$$
(x-y)^2+(u-v)^2=-620.
$$
The obtained contradiction gives the required one.

Comment: Interesting! But how did you conclude that $A$ and $B$ are of that form? I didn't get this part.

Comment: Just compare the two matrices: 
$$\begin{pmatrix}x&y\\z&u\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\b&a\end{pmatrix}$$
and
$$\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\b&a\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}x&y\\z&u\end{pmatrix}$$